# C# EPPlus resize pictures to fit in the cell

Tags: c#, image, epplus

I am trying to place a picture into B1 cell. picture is getting inserted but height is getting bigger than original image. **how automatically height is getting stretched?**

I am using EPPlus version **4.0.6.0** & .Net version **4.5.2**. **using VS IDE 2013**.

Here is the output screenshot.

[image]

Desired output screenshot

[image]

here is the code sample which i used to place **picture into B1 cell**.

```
imgCompanyLogo = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\tridip\Desktop\Test1\www_files\image002.png");
ws.Column(2).Width = Convert.ToDouble((45 + 0.11));
ws.Row(1).Height = Convert.ToDouble((46.5 + 0.11));
ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("Logo", imgCompanyLogo);
pic.SetPosition(0, 0, 1, 0);
pic.SetSize(316, 60);
```

if i commented or not commented this line `pic.SetPosition(0, 0, 1, 0);` but always getting same output where picture is getting stretched.

see the original image how it looks like. link here https://ibb.co/PCxw3v0

what is the mistake in my code? or suggest a fix by which i can get my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved. i place image at the end before saving excel file.
here is the code.

```
    if (imgCompanyLogo != null)
    {
        decimal mdw = ws.Workbook.MaxFontWidth;
        int pixelHeight = (int)(ws.Row(1).Height / 0.75);
        int pixelWidth = (int)decimal.Truncate(((256 * (decimal)ws.Column(2).Width + decimal.Truncate(128 / (decimal)mdw)) / 256) * mdw);
    
        var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("Test", imgCompanyLogo);
        picture.SetSize(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
        //picture.EditAs = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.eEditAs.TwoCell;
        picture.SetPosition(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }
output.Save();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the SetPosition method,this method will resize the picture.

```
                    pic.From.Row = rowIndex - 1;
                    pic.From.Column = columnIndex - 1;
                    pic.To.Row = rowIndex;
                    pic.To.Column = columnIndex;
                    pic.SetSize(100, 100);
```